# My Fahrenheit-Celsius calculator does not work

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make a calculator that converts Fahrenheit to Celsius (and the other way around) for some practice. The user has to put a value for Fahrenheit in the input, and then click the convert button, which shows the result.

```
<input id="ftemp" placeholder="Insert Fahrenheit">
<button id="convertC">Convert</button>
<p id="result"><p>
```

I added an event listener for when the user clicks the convert button.

```
document.getElementById("convertC").addEventListener("click", print("result", toCelsius(document.getElementById(ftemp).value)));
```

The code is a bit hard to understand. On the addEventListener section, I put the "click" for when the user clicks the convert button. After, I put a print function. I know its not python. Before, I made a print function that looks a bit like this:

```
function print(id, text) {
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;
}
```

In `print("result", toCelsius(document.getElementById(ftemp).value))` the "result" id is the final Celsius result. Then I added a toCelsius function, which was:

```
function toCelsius(temp) {
return (temp - 32) * (5 / 9);
}
```

Then I added `document.getElementById(ftemp).value` got the value from the input box, so the toCelsius function would convert the calue into Celsius, which the print function would print into the result.

**Final Result**

HTML:

```
<input id="ftemp" placeholder="Insert Fahrenheit">
<button id="convertC">Convert</button>
<p id="result"><p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function print(id, text) {
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;
}
function toCelsius(temp) {
return (temp - 32) * (5 / 9);
}
document.getElementById("convertC").addEventListener("click", print("result", toCelsius(document.getElementById(ftemp).value)));
```

Now onto the problem. The expected result is when I click the convert button, it converts the value I typed and prints it. But what happens the `<p>` just says -17.7778, because that is Celsius for 0 degrees Fahrenheit, and I didn't even click the convert button. And when I put a value in the text input, and actually click the button, nothing happens. The console says I didn't do anything wrong, so can you tell me where I messed up? I suspect it has something to do with the addEventListener, because it still printed the right Celsius value.

If you just skipped to the end, you should still probably read the final result section, if you want to answer my question.

Comment: You are executing the print function immediately. Instead, you'd need to pass a function as the handler which then calls print. For example try putting `() =>` before `print`

Comment: Or as opposed to all the interjected comments, you could just list your code *as-is* so that it can be at least be attempted to be run (reproducible) by someone in the community.

Comment: try this.. document.getElementById("convertC").addEventListener("click", ()=>print("result", toCelsius(document.getElementById("ftemp").value)));